# How to get a Kafka message in google colab

Tags: python, apache-kafka, google-colaboratory

I'm very new to Apache Kafka and trying to write my first code using Google Colab. I wrote such a line:

[image]

Is it any possibility to get/print this message?

Comment: Where do you want to print it? When you send it with the producer, you can retrieve it thanks to a consumer that will listen to that topic (in your case : "example").

Comment: @Ludal in the same colab where the producer is described

Comment: Oh ok, I'm afraid I can't help you, sorry

Answer (score 0):

This method returns a Future. You would call `.get()` on a Future, which the kafka-python documentation describes, but this gets you metadata such as the topic, partition, etc, not the record itself

You wouldn't use a Producer to "get data *from* Kafka", you'd use a Consumer